# The radio button doesn't react when I click on it, what could be the problem?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, radio-button

So I have a simple form with a few inputs and two radio buttons, but when I click any of them, they seem like they don't react. What could be the problem?

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import "./style.css";

export default function LargeForm() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    id: uuid(),
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    sex: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    email: "",
    contact: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (value, type) => {
    setNewUser((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [type]: value };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      newUser.firstName &&
      newUser.lastName &&
      newUser.dateOfBirth &&
      newUser.email &&
      newUser.contact &&
      newUser.password
    ) {
      setPeople([...people, newUser]);
      setNewUser({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        sex: "",
        dateOfBirth: "",
        email: "",
        contact: "",
        password: ""
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Error!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="container" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName" className="label">
            First name:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.firstName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "firstName")}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lastName" className="label">
            Last name:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.lastName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "lastName")}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="sex" className="label">
            Sex:
          </label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="male"
            name="sex"
            value={newUser.sex}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "sex")}
          />
           <label for="male">Male</label> {" "}
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="female"
            name="sex"
            value={newUser.sex}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "sex")}
          />
          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="dateOfBirht" className="label">
            Date of birth:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="dateOfBirht"
            name="dateOfBirht"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.dateOfBirth}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "dateOfBirth")}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="email" className="label">
            Email:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="Email"
            name="Email"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.email}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "email")}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="contact" className="label">
            Contact:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="contact"
            name="contact"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.Contact}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "contact")}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="password" className="label">
            Password:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            className="input"
            value={newUser.password}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "password")}
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      {people.map((person) => {
        return (
          <div className="list" key={person.id}>
            {person.firstName}
            <br />
            {person.lastName}
            <br />
            {person.sex}
            <br />
            {person.dateOfBirth}
            <br />
            {person.email}
            <br />
            {person.contact}
            <br />
            {person.password}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

The CodeSandbox link is given below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-react-5vj5g?file=/src/useReducer/exampleForm/LargeForm.js

Comment: When you are posting your question, please post a code snipped also so that someone looking at your question can quickly glance over it. Also codesadbox or any other online service could break links or stop working and that makes your question naked with only your question as a text. I added it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are setting `handleSubmit` to be called on `onClick` of the form. That means anything that you do on that `form` HTML element it will be a click event first.

It is a small change from `onClick` to `onSubmit`

```
...
<form className="container" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
...
```

Also the part where you define `radio` inputs, you should use `checked` state of that input and set `value` to be the desired value for that `radio` input:

```js
<label htmlFor="sex" className="label">
  Sex:
</label>
<input
  type="radio"
  id="male"
  name="sex"
  value='male'
  checked={newUser.sex === 'male'}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "sex")}
/>
 <label for="male">Male</label> {" "}
<input
  type="radio"
  id="female"
  name="sex"
  value='female'
  checked={newUser.sex === 'female'}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "sex")}
/>
<label for="female">Female</label>
```

Comment: That onClick was suposed to be onSubmit. I didn't even realize that mistake until now. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I figured out that was one of those blind spot mistakes. Glad I helped.

Comment: Second part of your answer was a copy from my answer and link @MarioPetrovic. But it's ok

Answer (score 1):

You must use `checked` attribute to specify which item is checked. And use `value` property to set the value of any radio item. You also define `onClick` attribute on Form tag that it's incorrect and you must use `onSubmit` instead of that.

This is the correct link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-react-forked-4wic3

Answer (score 1):

change onClick to onSubmit. it'll work